# Specific access to elements of dictionary in django template

Tags: django, templates, dictionary

I have a dict, keys in this dictionary is some ID that I take from object by calling some method. In django template I need something like this

```
id = object.get_id
element = dict[id]
```

Comment: You need to read: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Comment: If you don't know the `id` when writing the template, you'll have a terrible time doing this in the template. There are inefficient ways, like iterating through all the keys in the dict, but you'll have a much better time if you do this kind of logic in your view instead.

Comment: I think, you could also use {% with id=object.get_id %}<span>dict.id</span>{% endwith %}

Comment: you have to do it in the view